# How do I tag the most interesting parts of a video?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, attention

This is a follow-up question from my previous question [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/13560). I'm new to ML/DL, and one thing I need to do is to use a machine or deep learning video attention model which as the name suggests, can tag which parts of a video is probably more interesting and absorbs more viewer attention.

Do we have an available model to do that? If not, how to do it?